# Getting Error while Exporting GridView To Excel in .xlsx format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-2010, export-to-excel, aspxgridview

I want to export GridView to excel(in .xlsx format).
Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 GridView gv;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setGridView();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    string fileName = "TestExcelFile.xlsx";
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; // Works perfectly for .xls files
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}

private void setGridView()
{
    gv = new GridView();
    Queue q = new Queue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        q.Enqueue(i);
    }
    gv.DataSource = q;
    gv.DataBind();
 }
}
```

If I keep response content type as : `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";` then it works perfectly for excel's .xls format.

But for the excel file to be in .xlsx format, content type should be : `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";`.

**I can use .xls format but the problem is .xls format can hold only 64000 records and as per my project requirement I will get nearly 100000 (100K) rows. So I have to export it to an excel with .xlsx format to hold records above 64000.**

Here is the error Text & Image:
**"Excel cannot open the file 'TestExcelFile[2].xlsx' because the file format for the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."**
[image: Error while opening the exported Excel File]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have no idea what a "Lakh" is, but I guess it's more than 65535, but as far as I know the ASP.NET Gridview can't export it to XLSX format directly since it outputs it as raw HTML.

I'd recommend that you have a look at some component like EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which is much more flexible and scalable to work with for your requirements.

What you can do, as a workaround, though this won't be as elegant, would be to try the following code:

```
protected void btnExportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=output.xlsx");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvData.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            for (int idxColumn = 0; idxColumn < row.Cells.Count; idxColumn++)
                row.Cells[idxColumn].Attributes.Add("class", "xlText");
    }

    gvData.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

    string appendStyle = @"<style> .xlText { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
    Response.Write(appendStyle);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

I've used that one Before for Excel 2007, but it's a hack and not very elegant.

Comment: 1Lakh is 100000(100 thousands)

Comment: Right on, well, try out the code above or check out the Component. Any of these SHOULD solve your issue. I've generated xlsx files with 500'000+ rows from EPPlus on regular basis.

Comment: EPPlus can be used with response object?

Comment: You generate the Excel file as a memorystream and return it using the response object to the client, yes.

Comment: Ok, then you're option is EPPlus for this task. Check the page and look at the documentation, they have a link to some nice examples there.

Comment: I am considering EPPLUS as an valid answer for this and marking it as solution.

Comment: Thanks, and do use it, it's a pretty simple and yet powerful solution to solve most Excel tasks.

Comment: I have a query.. The excel generating is opening in proected view, I have to explicitly click on 'enable editing' to edit option.. Could you please help me how to directly open it in enable editing mode?

Comment: That one can't be resolved sadly. If it was possible to achieve this from the server side, the whole Point with that view would be removed. It's there to protect the users from downloading and opening harmful files and is explicitly controlled in the Excel application itself.

Comment: Hey! but you know before using epplus I was able to generate excel file directly in enable editing "mode".

Comment: Well, it wasn't an Excel per definition, it was merely a HTML markup formatted so that it understands. With the .xlsx extension comes the protected view.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this (which will only convince you to get [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), as JaggenSWE mentioned before me, when the relative amounts of work are compared) is using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` tools...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

string path = @"C:\testoutput\output.xlsx";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;

oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = false; //This can be fun to leave enabled though :)
oXL.UserControl = false;

oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
oSheet = oBook.ActiveSheet;

//This part can take a while, so throwing it into an async method elsewhere may be a thought
for (int x = 0; x < gv.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < gv.Columns.Count; y++)
    {
        oSheet.Cells[x + 2, y + 1] = gv.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToString();
    }
}
oBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);

oBook.Close(); //Don't forget this because the program will not close it automatically!!!
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question... I dont want the file to be saved at any specific path as you are defining in `string path = @"C:\testoutput\output.xlsx";` I want to render everything thorugh Response only.